# Android video player and track selection

Tags: android, video

i am trying to make a vod streaming app. I have researched  and have found some good video players. for example google's ExoPlayer and some other libraries. But i need a vido player capable of open a dialog for selecting subtitle tracks and switch audio tracks on multi language videos

VLC player and MxPlayer have this features, but i need to use an embedded player, not an third party player.

for the record, the subtitles are already embedded into the videos, they are not on a separate file, and the audio tracks are also on the same video. So is just one video file with subtitle track and audio trakcs inside.

I hope you can help me providing me a self explanatory example of how can i make this. Please, thanks. You've always been great helping me.

Answer (score -2):

ExoPlayer has a default track selector mechanism and the ability to add custom track selectors so I think it will meet your needs.

The developer guide is here: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Tthere is also an example on GitHub which you can look at the track selector in: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer.

One note on your question - when you say the subtitles are embedded in the videos, I assume you mean they are already included in the video file or container - i.e. in the mp4 file.

An mp4 is a 'container' and it can contain multiple video, audio, subtitle tracks etc.

This allows a player to play the video track and different subtitle and audio tracks as required by the viewer.

If the subtitles are actually embedded in the video stream itself, i.e. encoded into the video frames, then you can't switch then (or not without a large amount of work by the client).

Comment: Can you provide me a less complex example? i already cloned and compiled exoplayer example but its hard to me to add just what i need to my app. Thx